# On the lack of "int main(int argc, char* argv[])" knowledge

Tags: c++, parsing, bash

I'm a Physicist and, usually, I just want to get the calculations done and that's all I really need. Nevertheless I had been using

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

and its very pleasing how the binary becomes flexible in levels that I didn't expect i.e. initializing variables

```
~$ ./program.exe a b c   (a, b and c are numbers in this case, not letters ok?)
```

So the question is

***How do I "parse" or "pipe" things from one to another in this manner (or other) *without* using files?***

Example: say that "a.exe" gives a set of "X-Y" points (like on a spreadsheet) and I what to plug that on "b.exe". Or say I use a bash/awk script to format the output format of "a.exe" to plot it on, say, gnuplot.

**-----------------------------------------**

Hi again. I'm trying to do this but, I've still got problems.

To see what I'm doing wrong I wrote the simplest program

```
   #include <cstdio>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++)
     cout << "argv[" << i << "]= " << argv[i] << endl;  


   getchar();   
   return 0;
   }
```

and made a file with the content (lets say it is "test.dat")

```
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4
 5 
 6
```

since I don't want to read the content of the file *on my program*, I just want to "throw it" to it, so I've tried

```
more test.dat | ./program.exe
```

or even

```
 ./program.exe << EOF
 1 2 3 4 5
 EOF
```

but it doesn't work and I thought it should.

Thanks again.

Comment: This question should be on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can use the xargs command to change file contents into command line arguements.  `cat test.dat | xargs preogram.exe`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing the two concepts of arguments and piping.

The parameters that you specify in the `main` function handles arguments, not piping.

The "pipe" character `|` is used to do piping, and that doesn't affect the arguments, it affects the input and output stream. The `<` and `>` can be used to pipe from and to a file.

What you append after a program call is arguments, example:

```
progam.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

These will be parsed by the bolerplate code in the program, and end up in the `argv` array when the `main` function is called.

When you use the `<` character to pipe a file into a program, the content of the file will be sent to the input stream of the program:

```
program.exe < data.txt
```

The program will not have console input (screen and keyboard), instead it's fed data from the file.

When you use the `>` character to pipe to a file, the output of the program goes to the file instead of the console. Example:

```
program.exe > result.txt
```

When you use the `|` character to pipe from one program to another, the output stream of the first program is the input stream of the other program. Example:

```
program.exe | sort.exe
```

Everything that the first program writes to the output stream goes into the input stream of the other program. If you don't specify any input or output files, the first program has console input, and the second program has console output. So, the data flows through the two programs like this:

```
[console] --> [program.exe] --> [sort.exe] --> [console]
```

You can pipe several programs, so that the data flows from the first program to the last. Example:

```
program.exe | sort.exe | more.exe
```

The data then flows throught all three programs:

```
[console] --> [program.exe] --> [sort.exe] --> [more.exe] --> [console]
```

(The `.exe` extension is normally not needed when specifying a program, I just included it here to distinguish clearly between programs, arguments and files.)

Comment: Good answer- is it worth adding, for the benefit, that getting input from the input stream can be done with `scanf`, and the way to send output to the output stream is with `printf`

Comment: Also, it's important to realize that these operators (<, > and |) are all implemented by the shell in typical environments, the actual program binary doesn't have to do anything and is in fact not aware of the operators being used, typically. They don't appear in `argv[]`.

Comment: That helped a lot Guffa. Now I know what it stands for. Nevertheless I just tried another thing and I still don't get what I need. I just edit the post. I don't want to read, i want to "throw" stuff to the program.

Comment: If you want to combine piping and arguments use xargs.
cat data.txt | xargs | program

Comment: that worked but using "cat data.text | xargs ./program" thank you KarlM